ASS/SSA subtitles hard coded using ffmpeg are highly antialiased
I am using ASS/SSA format for hard coding captions on the video. These are relevant parts of my .ass file:
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, BackColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding
Style: s0, Montserrat-Black, 60, &H0015CCFA, &H001C1CB9, &H77000000, &H00000000, 1, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, , 0, 1, 2, 2 , 2, 0, 0, 0, 1

[Events]
Format: Start, End, Style, Text
Dialogue: 00:0:43.8,00:0:46.55,s0,{\pos(540,1550)\fscx50\fscy50\t(0,100,\fscx100\fscy100)\org(10540,-8450)\t(100,600,\frz0.10)\t(600,1100,\frz-0.10)\t(1100,1600,\frz0.10)\t(1600,2100,\frz-0.10)\t(2100,2600,\frz0.10)\t(2600,3100,\frz-0.10)\t(3100,3600,\frz0.10)\k3463}ME FOR WHATEVER

And to hard code on the video, I use following ffmpeg command:
ffmpeg -i video_filepath -vf ass={ass_filepath} -c:a copy -y out_path

This works as intended, except the captions are highly antialiased.
Here is a small section of result: https://gifyu.com/image/S5ZD6
By the way, all chat bots have failed to answer this.
